# Expected value of $e^x$ as $X\sim exp(\lambda)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution, expected-value

Let $X\sim exp(\lambda)$

> Calculate the Expected value of $$Y=e^X$$

Is there any elegant way to do it?

Comment: I assume it is $Y=e^X$ not $Y=e^x$.

Comment: Look for mgf of X

Comment: @Dave Fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What's not-elegant in, ($\lambda > 1$),

$$E(e^X) = \int_0^{\infty} e^x\lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx = \frac {\lambda}{\lambda-1}\int_0^{\infty} (\lambda-1) e^{-(\lambda-1) x} dx = \frac {\lambda}{\lambda-1} $$ ?

Seen (comically) narrowly, Mathematical Statistics is a field were people spend their life finding pairs of integrands and domains over which the integrands integrate to unity... for us mortals to use this repository of knowledge.

Comment: I think you threw a sign. If $1-\lambda<0$ then that expectation is negative.

Comment: @Dave. Silly. Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $E(Y)=E(e^X)=E(e^{1\cdot X})=m_X(1)$ where $m_X$ is the moment generating function of $X$. So if you know the moment generating function of an $\exp(\lambda)$ distribution, then you're good to go.

Note: for this method you need $\lambda>1$.

Comment: And if $\lambda \le 1$?

Comment: @UmShmum try doing the integration. It is simply $$E(Y)=\int_0^\infty e^x\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx$$ What goes wrong when $\lambda\leq 1$? For instance, try $\lambda=1$ and $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}$.